# Custom digital signature of a wallet

Tags: wallets, signature, private-key, keccak, eip712

I would like to get a custom signature from a wallet. What I mean is, according to [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) the signature algorithm used in Ethereum is kekkac256; I would like instead to use a **[custom signature algorithm](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518.html#page-6)** in order to create a valid JSON web signature. Is there a way to do it wihtout directly asking the private key to the wallet owner?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to write a custom function. For example, related [python](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-account/blob/29b9b545cd176fb37c77338ebfc22eeddca98d06/eth_account/messages.py#L121) and [javascript](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util/blob/main/src/sign-typed-data.ts) code has the keccak baked in.